# Deleting File On Ftp Server?

Tags: c#, winforms, ftp

i am trying to delete a file from my FTP website but i cannot seem to get the code to work could anyone help?, i get no error's it just doesn't do anything.

```
private FtpWebRequest deleteRequest(string uri, string method)
{
    var r = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    string Delete = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;

    r.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(TxtUsername.Text, TxtPassword.Text);
    r.Method = Delete = listView1.SelectedItems.ToString();
    return r;
}
```

The rest of the code.

```
    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = TxtServer.Text + listView1.SelectedItems.ToString();
        deleteRequest(textBox1.Text, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code i ended up using thank you all for the help really appreciate it.

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResultLabel.Text = "Deleting: " + listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
        ResultLabel.Show();
        this.Refresh();
        textBox1.Text = TxtServer.Text + listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(textBox1.Text);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(TxtUsername.Text, TxtPassword.Text);
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        ResultLabel.Text = "Deleted: " + listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
        response.Close();
    }
```

I just fully rewrote the code and tried again and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `r.GetResponse()`. You really don't need to return your request from your method.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the "DELETE" method with whatever is selected in your ListView.

---

The following line:

```
r.Method = Delete = listView1.SelectedItems.ToString();
```

is the same as these two:

```
Delete = listView1.SelectedItems.ToString();
r.Method = Delete;
```

So that `Delete` first gets the value of whatever is in your `SelectedItems`, and then you use that value as the `Method`. That's probably not what you had in mind.

Comment: I suggest you write yourself a piece of code to do nothing but delete the file. Forget about text boxes and listviews and things like that. Just write the code to delete. You'll need to call `r.GetResponse()` after you build the request. It is `GetResponse` which actually issues the request.

Comment: i got it to work now :) thanks ill answer my own question with my solution